# How can I allow the user "postgres" on one server to rsync to another?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to get this command to work as the user postgres (so I can ship wal files):

```
rsync -a /tmp/test postgres@server2:/tmp/test
```

But I get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've run `ssh-keygen` `` eval `ssh-agent` `` and `ssh-add` as postgres user on server1. keygen created `/var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` and I can see that it's sent by using `ssh -vvv postgres@server2`.

On server2 I've created `/var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/authorized_keys` put the contents of id_rsa.pub form server1 in it. It's owned by postgres user and group and chmod 600. The `.ssh` directory is also owned by postgres and chmod 700.

I can see from verbose sshd logging on server2 that `Failed publickey for postgres...`

postgres user on both servers: `postgres:x:106:114:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash`

ssh -vvv postgres@server2

```
...
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f468e434000)
debug2: key: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

server2 sshd_config (commented lines removed)

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
```

server2 auth log

```
Jan 16 03:54:21 ip-10-28-26-251 sshd[7972]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Jan 16 03:54:21 ip-10-28-26-251 sshd[7972]: Connection from 10.28.123.97 port 49377
Jan 16 03:54:21 ip-10-28-26-251 sshd[7972]: Failed publickey for postgres from 10.28.123.97 port 49377 ssh2
Jan 16 03:54:21 ip-10-28-26-251 sshd[7972]: Connection closed by 10.28.123.97 [preauth]
```

What am I missing? I'm guessing that sshd isn't looking at my authorized_keys file on server2

Comment: Can you paste the output of `grep postgres /etc/passwd` in question?

Comment: passwd line added

Comment: I am not seeing any issue. Can you add following info as well to the question: 1) `ssh -vvv postgres@server2` verbose info. 2) `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config` (server2). 3) `cat ~/.ssh/config` (server1)

Comment: Added. `~/.ssh/config` does not exist

Comment: Yes, I also think same. `sshd` isn't looking at your `authorized_keys`

Comment: Run the server in debug mode too if you can: /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Comment: Check the permissions on `/var` and `/var/lib` as well as on `/var/lib/postgres`. If any of them is too generous, sshd will refuse to use an authorized_keys file in any subdirectory, as it would be possible to move directories around and thus circumvent the protections further down in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your slave server allows key authentication, you only need to update `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if you've set `AllowedUsers`, in which case you need to ensure `postgres` is in that list.

Other than that, just `ssh-keygen` (leave private key passphrase empty), and then add an `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` directory/file to the slave server. The home directory for `postgres` is `/var/lib/postgresql`, but if you do these operations while `su`'d as the `postgres` user, you can just use `~`, not to mention you won't have to `chown` anything, because `postgres` will own the generated ssh keys on the master server, and `postgres` will own the created directory/file on the slave server.

Be sure to set the file permissions securely on both the master and slave server:

```
# On master
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts  # this one won't exist until you SSH once

# On slave
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

You need following entry in `sshd_config` of server2:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Neither `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` or `AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` make a difference I'm afraid. (Restarted sshd after config change)

Comment: Jake, I am not sure about this. It is worth to try with full path for AuthorizedKeysFile, though it is not the correct way.

Comment: Tried that too :( I'll have to go through it all with a fine-toothed comb, no doubt there's a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling selinux system wide is a poor solution.

It's much better to create a policy module that will allow the specific action you need.

Here is what I did in RHEL6:

I cleared my audit log, restarted rsyslogd, and repeated the issue.

Next, use audit2allow to see the human readable problem:

```
# audit2allow -w -a
type=AVC msg=audit(1438288591.000:8525): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=6063 comm="sshd" path="/var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys" dev="dm-0" ino=920234 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:postgresql_db_t:s0 tclass=file
        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

type=AVC msg=audit(1438288591.000:8525): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=6063 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev="dm-0" ino=920234 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:postgresql_db_t:s0 tclass=file
        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

type=AVC msg=audit(1438288591.000:8526): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6063 comm="sshd" path="/var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys" dev="dm-0" ino=920234 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:postgresql_db_t:s0 tclass=file
        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

After making sure there were no extra denials going on, and that these were specific to the issue at hand, create an selinux module to allow sshd to read, open, and getattr for postgres authorized_keys:

```
# audit2allow -a -M sshd_read_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys
```

Now install the resulting module:

```
# semodule -i sshd_read_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys.pp
```

I copied this module to the peer postgres server and installed there as well.  I can now ssh with public key authentication between boxes as postgres, and I am still in an selinux enforcing state.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on debug logs on your existing ssh server. In file /etc/ssh/sshd_config change 

`LogLevel DEBUG3`

if the reason for unsuccessful login is
`Could not open authorized keys '/var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied` and access rights to authorized_keys seems ok, then this command will help

`restorecon -FRvv /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/`

[explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688844/sshd-gives-error-could-not-open-authorized-keys-although-permissions-seem-corr)

Answer (score 0):

I found Gregory's answer only partially worked for me, although it pointed me in the right direction. I found a few rules/policies were needed, and could only be generated in a specific order.

Since the `ssh-copy-id` command only works if the the other end has a password, you will need to `scp` the public key around and adjust the user and permissions accordingly. This way no password needs to be created and one possible access point is kept closed.

To create a postgres user key and allow it to ssh into itself, but if you carry that key to another server it will also work.

```
# su postgres
$ cd
$ ssh-keygen # [enter....] * 
$ cd .ssh/
$ cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
$ chmod 0600 authorized_keys
```

Each error needs occur before a rule can be generated for it, therefore after every policy added another attempt to ssh with just enter on the password prompts is needed.

```
$ ssh postgres@192.168.0.10
```

ssh into self for simplicity, but it still works. After it errors:

```
$ exit
# audit2allow -a -M sshd_open_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys
# semodule -i sshd_open_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys.pp
# su postgres
$ ssh postgres@192.168.0.10 
$ exit
# audit2allow -a -M sshd_read_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys
# semodule -i sshd_read_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys.pp
# su postgres
$ ssh postgres@192.168.0.10 
$ exit
# audit2allow -a -M sshd_getattr_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys
# semodule -i sshd_read_postgres_ssh_authorized_keys.pp
# su postgres
$ ssh postgres@192.168.0.10
```

*should work this time*

NOTE: '#' indicates root, but use sudo, I wrote it this way for ease - not to indicate best practices

Answer (score -1):

SELinux was causing this issue for me on Redhat 6.5. Fixed using:

setenforce Permissive